# Python webscrape text inside of multiple tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to return some values in a yahoo finance page. They are wrapped in  tags. I was able to get it to return these values

```
543.46
546.8
None
None
595.73
0.65
```

I'm having problems with the None values that I got. I should be returning "537.51 x 100" and "537.60 x 100" The numbers do change because of the website. I just need that format to be the output. The particular html I am looking at from the source page is below. This code is inside more tags, but BeautifulSoup doesn't care about that.

```
<tr>
<th scope="row" width="48%">
    Prev Close:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    543.46</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th scope="row" width="48%">
    Open:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    546.80</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th scope="row" width="48%">
    Bid:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    <span id="yfs_b00_aapl">
        536.55</span>
    <small> x 
        <span id="yfs_b60_aapl">
            100</span>
    </small>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><
th scope="row" width="48%">
    Ask:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    <span id="yfs_a00_aapl">
        536.63</span>
    <small> x 
        <span id="yfs_a50_aapl">
            100</span>
    </small>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th scope="row" width="48%">
    1y Target Est:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    595.73</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th scope="row" width="48%">
    Beta:</th>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
    0.65</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the third and and fourth values have some extra tags such as  and  inside the td tag so it is returning None which I don't want. My code is here:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&q1=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


for data in soup.find_all('td', attrs = {'class': 'yfnc_tabledata1'} ) [0:6]:
        print (data.string) #I have .string so it wouldn't print the tags, only the text. I would rather have it return strings before it needs to print.
```

I'm thinking I need another for loop inside the first one that will account for the extra tags or maybe if statements. I'm not sure what the coding would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd do a nooby way for this:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&q1=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for data in soup.find_all('td', class_="yfnc_tabledata1")[0:6]:
    if data.parent.name == "tr":
            print (data.text)
```

Outputs:

```
>>>
543.46
546.80
536.50 x 100
536.60 x 100
595.73
0.65
>>>
```

Works good enough :)

**Note: I changed to urllib2 for the urlopen function.**

You could also use either of the following:

```
for data in soup.find_all('td', class_="yfnc_tabledata1")[0:6]:
    print (data.text)
```

or

```
for data in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'yfnc_tabledata1'})[0:6]:
    print (data.text)
```

Comment: This didn't fix the main problem. I don't want the None values. Quoted from my original post: I should be returning "537.51 x 100" and "537.60 x 100"

Comment: user2859603 Added two other alternatives

Comment: Glad it helped, all three options should work but I personally would use the first option as it also checks that the parent is `tr` just incase they do something funny with their website.

Comment: yup, I used your first option. Now I gotta figure out how to write each value into a different excel cell. I have four lines that will help for this goal.                                                   "from openpyxl import load_workbook"                                  "wb = load_workbook(filename = r'Another_book.xlsx')"
"sheet_ranges = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Pi')" "sheet_ranges.cell('F8').value = data.text"

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer is that in bs4 they have added [`.strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings).

your code could look something like:

```
for data in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'yfnc_tabledata1'})[0:6]:
    print '--> ',(''.join(data.strings))
```

the "\n" characters are preserved so you can strip and recombine the strings to your liking.

Comment: Need's an if statement to check for the `"x"` in your version as he wants two of the values to appear as `"None"` instead of `536.52 x 100` and `536.61 x 100` or a check to see if data has `small` or `span`.

Comment: @Hyflex actually that is what his and your code shows and he explicitly states that he wants `536.52 x 100` not `None`

Comment: My bad, you are correct, a little unclear as I didn't read his comments fully.

Comment: I put your print line in and got a syntax error. Was there something else I'm supposed to add to that line to get the values I need?

Comment: user2859603, care to give the syntax error and also show us the code you tried? Try: `print ('--> ',(''.join(data.strings)))` as you're using python 3

Comment: @user2859603 no the print statement looks ok (maybe parens not as I have them.  anyway you could remove the `'--> ',` as it was just there for a visual demarcation as I left the carriage returns inplace.